# Twitter API screen_name and name not working only text

Tags: php, api, twitter

I'm using the twitter API to get the tweet information of a tag. I'm able to get the tweet using the [text] from the array but when I use [screen_name] to get the username and the [name] to get their name they don't work. Also I can't seem to get this to work with mentions which i'm sure it's meant to any idea here guys?

Thanks again.

```
<?
function buildBaseString($baseURI, $method, $params) {
    $r = array();
    ksort($params);
    foreach($params as $key=>$value){
        $r[] = "$key=" . rawurlencode($value);
    }
    return $method."&" . rawurlencode($baseURI) . '&' . rawurlencode(implode('&', $r));
}

function buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth) {
    $r = 'Authorization: OAuth ';
    $values = array();
    foreach($oauth as $key=>$value)
        $values[] = "$key=\"" . rawurlencode($value) . "\"";
    $r .= implode(', ', $values);
    return $r;
}

function returnTweet(){
    $oauth_access_token         = "1140776708-Z03sg5mVXqc4il9ff1EfBcbE5aycwlfslDni2Lt";
    $oauth_access_token_secret  = "gr6RbsvIq9kUoREjVkwlOgHSwJJU7do91NpCz87PKNMOz";
    $consumer_key               = "Ub3R51niGzjJIFQtCDrb7tvjJ";
    $consumer_secret            = "T74d8SJYDET9n8T4PDI7aobNwo9M6fkmQI0hHhWd9ntzY9y5hL";

    $twitter_timeline           = "user_timeline";  //  mentions_timeline / user_timeline / home_timeline / retweets_of_me


        $request = array(
            'screen_name'       => 'matthutchings95',
            'count'             => '10'
        );

    $oauth = array(
        'oauth_consumer_key'        => $consumer_key,
        'oauth_nonce'               => time(),
        'oauth_signature_method'    => 'HMAC-SHA1',
        'oauth_token'               => $oauth_access_token,
        'oauth_timestamp'           => time(),
        'oauth_version'             => '1.0'
    );


        $oauth = array_merge($oauth, $request);


        $base_info              = buildBaseString("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/$twitter_timeline.json", 'GET', $oauth);
        $composite_key          = rawurlencode($consumer_secret) . '&' . rawurlencode($oauth_access_token_secret);
        $oauth_signature            = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_info, $composite_key, true));
        $oauth['oauth_signature']   = $oauth_signature;


        $header = array(buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth), 'Expect:');
        $options = array( CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
                          CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
                          CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/$twitter_timeline.json?". http_build_query($request),
                          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                          CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false);

        $feed = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
        $json = curl_exec($feed);
        curl_close($feed);

    return json_decode($json, true); 
}
    $tweet = returnTweet();

    #echo "Tweet No.1: " .$tweet[0]["text"];
    #echo '<br><br>';
    #echo "Tweet No.2: " .$tweet[1]["text"];
    #echo '<br><br>';
    #echo "Tweet No.3: " .$tweet[2]["text"];

    echo "Name: " .$tweet[0]["name"];
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo "Screen Name: " .$tweet[0]["screen_name"];
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo "Text: " .$tweet[0]["text"];
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo "Name: " .$tweet[1]["name"];
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo "Screen Name: " .$tweet[1]["screen_name"];
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo "Text: " .$tweet[1]["text"];
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo "Name: " .$tweet[2]["name"];
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo "Screen Name: " .$tweet[2]["screen_name"];
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo "Text: " .$tweet[2]["text"];
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo '<br><br>';
    print_r(returnTweet());

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "Screen Name: " .$tweet[0]["user"]["screen_name"];
echo "Screen Name: " .$tweet[0]["user"]["name"];
```

This is the [doc](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets) you need.

Comment: Thanks for mention the doc. I looking for this for a long time. Since then I am memorizing the fields coming in various responses :)